# Asterisk - how to change ringing timeout in realtime extension?

Tags: sip, asterisk

I use Asterisk 11 and try to change ringing timeout in MySQL realtime extention. It takes only 7~10 seconds to hangup automatically. I checked extension and it was like this.

here is a screeshot of extension table in asteriskrealtime mysql database.

[image]

```
SIP/5162860921,60
```

I changed this one to

```
SIP/5162860921,300
```

However, there was no change. How can I extend ringing timeout to 60 seconds?

**extensions.conf** (I use realtime database)

```
 [general]
 [globals]
 ;
 [from-sip]
 switch =>Realtime
```

**CLI log**

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [2000@from-sip:1] Dial("SIP/1000-00000000", "SIP/2000,30")
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/2000
    -- SIP/2000-00000001 is ringing
    -- Got SIP response 486 "Busy here" back from 14.63.12.134:5060
    -- SIP/2000-00000001 is busy
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:1/0/0)
    -- Executing [2000@from-sip:2] Answer("SIP/1000-00000000", "2000@from-sip")
       > 0x7fe6fc01bc00 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 223.62.180.115:47204
    -- Executing [2000@from-sip:3] hangup("SIP/1000-00000000", "")
  == Spawn extension (from-sip, 2000, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/1000-00000000'
```

Comment: @André I use realtime database. So there is not much information in extensions.conf.

Comment: What does a row from your database look like ?

Comment: @André I posted the screen shot.

Comment: @André I did change it to 300, but there was no change. I already restarted Asterisk, and it didn't work.

Comment: I think you missed it so I'm reposting it : "can you start Asterisk manually on the command line with high verbosity (-vvvv on the command line) and post its output ?"

Comment: @André I put CLI logs.. there is not that much information..

Comment: Add some more verbosity ("-vvvvvvvvvv") on the command line.

Comment: @André Maybe, I am using realtime database... that is why extension for realtime is different.. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was softphone application problem. I changed it to 60 seconds and it is working fine now.. SIP/1000,60 was right.